# Directory trees in C

Tags: c, data-structures, tree

So I have an assignment for my finals homework. It wants me to make a directory tree with some commands, similar to CMD. For example it will give me "make " and I will add directories to the tree. I got all the commands, syntax checking etc. down but I can't think how can I create the tree.

I thought about making a general tree for it, but there's a problem. When I add new folders, I need to check if it's already there and print a message if it is. I don't know a lot about tree structure but from what I know, to check them, I need to do firstChild, secondChild... until there is none which seems not the best way to do it.

I need ideas on this. I don't want you to do my homework, just a guideline for me to study would be more than enough.

Comment: Don't be afraid to share what you already have (for example the tree implementation in which you are not able to discover if a folder is already present). It will make easier for us to provide guidance. ;)

Answer (score 0):

To check if a directory path exists you can use fstat (see: https://linux.die.net/man/2/fstat).

But if you have the full path, you will parse that and check all if every part's parent exists.

For example if the path is /usr/local/bin/test you should check if `/usr` exists, then `/usr/local`, then `/usr/local/bin` and finally `/usr/local/bin/test`.

To do this you could write a recursive function calling itself with the last folder part stripped (unless you're at the root level) before checking if the specified path exists.